# Windows Defender says Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 is "unsafe to download"

Tags: windows-10, eclipse, windows-defender

I'm trying to download Kepler (Eclipse 4.3.2) from the eclipse.org site, but after pressing Open at the bottom of my browser in order to run the installation, instead a red-outlined box appears in its place at the bottom of the browser and announces, "eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip is unsafe to download and was blocked by Windows Defender SmartScreen."

Is it unsafe?

Comment: Windows Defender SmartScreen is entirely dependent on the number of Times a file is reported, if there is a false positive, report it so I can be reviewed.

Comment: @ni37oslib Not a recommendation regarding its current safety, but in the past, Kepler has been perfectly safe to use. However, it is theoretically possible that attackers may have gained access to the Eclipse servers and planted a malicious download (this happened with a program known as CCleaner a few years ago). Also, while this is conjecture, it's a possibility that it is considered "unsafe" because of the Java version it uses. Either way, Kepler is *not* the latest Eclipse release. You can (and likely should) get the latest release [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: Note that Eclipse Kepler is 10 releases out of date. Eclipse 2019-09 is the currently release with 2019-12 being released later this month.